# How to convert a list of string to a list of int

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list in a list

```
a = [['1','2','3','4'],['1','2','3','4'],['1','2','3','4']]
```

but i need it to be ints , 
im not sure where to use int() to change str to int

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension like so:

```
a = [['1','2','3','4'],['1','2','3','4'],['1','2','3','4']]
b = [ [int(j) for j in i] for i in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [51]: a = [['1','2','3','4'],['1','2','3','4'],['1','2','3','4']]

In [52]: [map(int, l) for l in a]
Out[52]: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

An example using nested [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [1]: a = [['1','2','3','4'],['1','2','3','4'],['1','2','3','4']]

In [2]: [[int(s) for s in l] for l in a]
Out[2]: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

```
>>> a = [['1','2','3','4'],['1','2','3','4'],['1','2','3','4']]
>>> map(lambda l: map(int, l), a)
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```